# Show that the transformation of a linearly dependent set is also linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How can I show that if $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\}$ is a linearly **dependent** set, and $T$ is a linear transformation, then $\{T(v_1), T(v_2), \dots,T(v_k)\}$ is linearly dependent.

Also, Let $ T : R^n \to R^m $ be a linear transformation, and let $V$ be a subspace of $R^m$. Show that the preimage $T^{-1}(V)$ is a subspace of $R^n$.

I know that it must satisfy $T(x+y)= T(x)+T(y)$ and $T(cx)=cT(x)$. But I'm not sure where to go with this?

Comment: Please, see edit!

Comment: @EricWofsey Can you give an example when it isn't true? Just curious

Comment: I can't, which is why I want to prove that this is true.

Comment: Consider the identity transformation. $\;$

Comment: Huh? My book says I must show it is linearly dependent, so I assume that it is.

Comment: Whether or not $\{T(v_{1}),\ldots,T(v_{k}) \}$ is linearly dependent depends very much on the particular choice of $T$, so you need more infmrtion for the first sentence.

Comment: OK, Eric has a point here. If the matrix is square and its determinant is zero, then it is possible that if the given vectors are lin independent, that the outcoming vectors (after subjecting the given vectors to the matrix) are line dependent, because one of the vectors could be mapped onto the zero vector. I worked out an example just like that. So the theorem is true apparently under certain constraints!

Comment: SEE EDIT. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  If $v_1,\dots, v_k$ is linearly dependent, that means we can find scalars $c_1,\dots,c_k$ such that $$c_1v_1+\dots+c_kv_k=0$$ and not every $c_i$ is $0$.  What do you get when you apply $T$ to both sides of the equation above?

Comment: Been trying to do this for about an hour. No luck.

Comment: Try starting with the case $k=2$.  What can you say about $T(c_1v_1+c_2v_2)$?